# Retaining vendor logo during bootiing Debian Buster

Tags: debian, boot, uefi

I would like to keep the UEFI logo while my Debian linux is booting, so no grub, no initramfs, no systemd messages (and no plymouth). I followed this description:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot

If I remove the "splash" from the kernel parameters, systemd ALWAYS writes to the console during the boot, so the UEFI logo disappears. How can I prevent that the logo disappear?

Comment: You could use the very same logo you don't want to dissappear as your splash screen. It will technically be overwritten instead of staying, but for the user the result is the same.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani That requires a way to capture the vendor logo...

Comment: Yes, I can use the very same logo, but I have to prevent display flickering too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here I am now:
I have added these kernel parameters to grub: nomodeset, and console=ttyS0
First, I tried it in my virtualbox machine. The UEFI logo is on the screen without any blinking... That what I wanted... buuuut after the system is booted in, the logo do not disappears :D

Comment: Hello. From the result that you describe, it does not seem like a working solution because the logo does not disappear after booting. Maybe, it would be better to [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594246/edit) and add this information as an update on what you tried? This way, it will be apparent to others that your question still needs a solution.